# Comment form - different title if no comment yet

Tags: comments, comment-form

this isn't major but would be nice. Would like to have 2 titles for the comment form, one that says "no comments yet start the discussion" and another that says "join the discussion". I've had a good look around but I can't see anything already posted about doing this. Can anyone assist? Skip.

(I may use different phrases but you get the general idea I'm sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_comments_number()` to get … well … the number of comments. In your theme’s `comments.php` you can use its return value to do something:

```
$num = (int) get_comments_number();

if ( 0 === $num )
    echo 'Be the first! But please don’t write just “First!”';
elseif ( 100 < $num )
    echo 'Yeah, add some noise. Nobody will read it.';
else
    echo 'Please write a comment';
```

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense to me. Will accept the answer and Toscho I recall you've helped me a few times so thank you very much.